# Google Map V2 on Android OS 8 (Samsung SGH-T959HABTMB)

Tags: android, service, google-play, android-2.2-froyo

I am facing a strange problem i created an android application which uses map when i run it on my `Motorola Atrix 2(OS 4.0.3)` it works fine but when i run it on `Samsung SGH-T959HABTMB (OS 2.0)` it does't show any map instead

```
isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext())
```

returns `ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED` on other hand my samsung device already have latest version of `google play services` which i checked programatically and compare it with my Atrix 2 `google play service version`

Following are configuration of my Samsung SGH

```
Android OS:8
**Google Play Service Version: 4030500**
Open Gl: 2.0
Internet?: true.
```

i am really confused i have latest version of Google Play Servies and application says that google play service update require, while there is no update available when i check it in Google App store.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but there was nothing wrong in my code, see my answer it may be helpful for you in your future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started integration of map in my app in early **Nov, 2013** i downloaded standard Google Play Services Library, Android 2.2 when it did't worked in `Android 2.2` and worked fine in `2.3 and greater`, after performing allot of search and reading Google setup guide again i found this

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

> Note: Google Play services 4.0.30 (released November 2013) and newer
>   versions require Android 2.3 or higher. If your app supports Android
>   2.2, you can continue development with the Google Play services SDK, but must instead install Google Play services for Froyo from the SDK
>   Manager.